# Prevent AWS lambda payload limit by send multipart response

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, limit, payload

I figure out an issue with AWS lambda with Amplify, I execute an API call that search product in other service and give me a JSON object in response (multiple products).

All work fine before I test with a huge list of products. In this case, I encountered this error: `Response payload size exceeded maximum allowed payload size (6291556 bytes).`

I want to use SQS and return a response when each queue finishes its job.

But I don't know how can I manage this multi-part response.

I was thinking about saving the JSON response in S3 to download it when it's finished but it's not a very good way to resolve this issue especially for a search when the number of combinations can generate a huge amount of files in my bucket.

If someone has an idea :)

Comment: Do you actually need to send that many search results to the client? Could you paginate them (if they genuinely are needed)?

Comment: No I can't paginate it because the final result of this is to create a ZIP file with all the assets of each products

Comment: @jarmod and obviously assets are not including int the JSON object (just to be the most clear as possible)

Comment: I'd be tempted to create that ZIP file server-side and then share it with the client via signed S3 URL, if possible.